# min/max values being stored in extent for every datetime column in a table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is it true that an extent stores max and min value for ***every*** datetime column in a table? I read it somewhere in the documentation. So say if I have 5 datetime columns in my table , all the extents for that table will have 5 min/max datetime value pairs representing those 5 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, while this is an implementation detail with no contractual obligation, this is true (at least for the current implementation).